# Change Gnome popup notification text colour

Tags: gnome, themes

How can I change the colour of the text below the title in popup notifications?

I have installed 20.04 (Gnome 3.36.1) with Adapta theme (specifically Adapta-Eta).

As you can see, the text below "Laravel Mix" is barely visible. I have tried to find the CSS selector in `/usr/share/themes/Adapta-Eta/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`, but none of the changes I have made have any effect.

[image: popup with dark text]

When I hover over the popup notification, the text colour changes to white(ish) legible text.

[image: popup with light]

Can someone please tell me which CSS selector corresponds to the text "Build successful"? Also, after making changes do I need reload the session for those changes to be reflected?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This issue is not related to Laravel Mix, which simply displays NPM asset build notifications. Using `notify-send` to generate test notifications results in the same issue.

When I execute `notify-send foo bar`, "foo" is light, while "bar" is barely visible:

[image: popup foo]

Comment: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tista/adapta` followed by `sudo apt-get install adapta-gtk-theme`. Then using gnome-tweaks I enabled the theme.

Comment: It's not Laravel Mix related. Even if I do `notify-send foo bar` from the CLI, "foo" is light, while "bar" is dark.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZMKl.gif

Comment: I have the same settings in tweaks. Weird. Might try a reinstall.

Comment: @Rob have you managed to solve this? I'm having the exact same issue right now, quite annoying. The selector is `.message-content` (at least for Arc theme) but whatever color i set there, it is only shown once I mouseover the notification. Before that it is barely visible.

Comment: @Zantsu I think it has something to do with the Adapta theme (it's no longer supported). I have changed to Materia https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme and it's working now.

Comment: @mj3c I'm going through the exactly the same situation as you, could you solve it?

Comment: @MartinPrado no, sorry... I am using Light notifications, couldn't bother with it anymore

Comment: @MartinPrado sorry no I gave up and switched to Materia theme instead. Have you tried modifying the CSS selectors as per Redman's answer below?

Comment: I already tried modifying all the attributes in the CSS file, it's a bug that transcends the theme

Answer (score 0):

You need to change or in my case add the following selectors:

> .notification-banner .message-title, .notification-banner:focus
> .message-title, .notification-banner:active .message-title {
> color: #eeeeec; } .notification-banner .message-content, .notification-banner:focus .message-content,
> .notification-banner:active .message-content {
> color: #eeeeec; }