# Unreadable Gnome Notifications

Tags: gnome, 20.04, themes, notification, personalization

**Bounty Edit:** [This post explains better the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232319/change-gnome-popup-notification-text-colour)

I've already made some posts asking how to adjust some little features from the themes you install in Gnome. In this case I've been manipulating the Arc-Black Theme with the following file for a while:
`usr/share/themes/Arc-Black/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` . However, I haven't found any line of code to change the text or background color of the notifications.
**Note:** The following picture shows what happens in the notification panel, but, it's the same case for the pop-up system notifications.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the following selectors to `gnome-shell.css`:

```
.notification-banner .message-title,
.notification-banner:focus .message-title,
.notification-banner:active .message-title { color: #ccc; }
.notification-banner .message-content,
.notification-banner:focus .message-content,
.notification-banner:active .message-content { color: #ccc; }
```

Hope this gives you what you need.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't help at all. As I edited, none of the CSS fixes can solve this problem. It also made me a little sad that the bounty expired before someone can truly understand the cause of this little glitch. I think is time to switch to another theme.